# MySQL Replication is online, but stalls with no errors or large transactions

Tags: mysql, replication

Have a replica that runs MySql 5.6 Replication. It has been running without issue for a long time. Now replication is running, but it pauses on a transaction and will not move until you issue a stop/start slave then it continues on without issue until the next stop hours later.

- Replication is running and never errors out

  ```
         Slave_IO_Running: Yes
        Slave_SQL_Running: Yes
  ```
- No matter how much time passes will not move past the transaction without a restart of replication.
- Error log show nothing except when I stop start the slave

```
    [Note] Error reading relay log event: slave SQL thread was killed
    [Note] Slave SQL thread exiting, replication stopped in log 'binlog123' at position 615277
    [Note] Slave I/O thread killed while reading event
    [Note] Slave I/O thread exiting, read up to log 'binlog123', position 615277
```

The only other thing I noticed was there were a few aborted connections

```
[Warning] Aborted connection 1054234389 to db: 'db1' user: 'user' host: '10.1.1.1' (Got an error reading communication packets)
```

I originally thought maybe it was stuck on a large transaction, but that is not the case. Transactions are all different on each break none are very large changes. My next thought is if it could be network related, but still can't solve why replication doesn't break or error. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: If you run `STOP SLAVE; START SLAVE;` does it recover?

Comment: Is the IO thread stuck or is the SQL thread stuck? If you compare the `SHOW MASTER STATUS` on the master to the `SHOW SLAVE STATUS` on the replica, do you see the `Master_Log_File`/`Read_Master_Log_Pos` advancing and keeping up with the coordinates on the master?

Comment: Yes the only recovery is to stop then start slave and replication continues on normally for hours/days without issue.

Comment: When comparing the I/O when the issue takes place show slave status shows nothing advancing. It’s like replication has stopped but sql and I/O both say yes as if they were working